# Flutter Sending Data to API (Image and Form)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I am able to send Images to the API but in case of form data it is not uploading to the API
can you help me out?

```
final String uploadUrl = 
 'https://demo.likemyfiles.com/DS/api/api_supervisor/upload_attend_selfie';
var res = await uploadImage(_imageFile.path, uploadUrl);
```

Image is uploaded through API but form is not

```
Future<String> uploadImage(filepath, url) async {
   // No issue in the keyWords
  Map mapeddate ={
  'date':"23-07-2021",
  'time':"05:37",
  'lat':"28.535517",
  'lng':"77.391029",
  'location':"Noida Sector 51 Gautam Buddh Nagar India, 201303",
  'activity_id':"4",
  'supervisor_id':"3",
};
var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url));
request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('userfile', filepath));
var res = await request.send();
return res.reasonPhrase;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP package cant send form data and you should use [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package

```
var formData = FormData.fromMap({
  'name': 'wendux',
  'age': 25,
  'file': await MultipartFile.fromFile('./text.txt', filename: 'upload.txt'),
 
});
var response = await dio.post('/info', data: formData);
```

Comment: Can you explain this why you have used this
'./text.txt'
'/info'

Comment: `./text.txt` is a sample and you should address your file and `/info` is your API URL address

Comment: There is a Reddit post on http vs Dio [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/mzhmnb/http_vs_dio/) I think it is worth thinking about it before adding extra dependencies,

Comment: yes, you're right, but every similar package has its own advantage and disadvantages and you should make the right choice between them for your project requirements. i prefer use Dio for upload/download (formData) and use HTTP for plain (JSON) requests.

Answer (score 2):

Using `MultipartRequest`, you can and add the form data as `fields`.

```dart
var uri = Uri.parse('https://example.com/create');
Map mapeddate ={
  'date':"23-07-2021",
  'time':"05:37",
  'lat':"28.535517",
  'lng':"77.391029",
  'location':"Noida Sector 51 Gautam Buddh Nagar India, 201303",
  'activity_id':"4",
  'supervisor_id':"3",
};
var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri)
  ..fields = mapedDate
  ..files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
      'userfile', filepath,
      contentType: MediaType('image', 'jpeg')));
var response = await request.send();
if (response.statusCode == 200) print('Uploaded!');
```

That example is taken from the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html) and adapted to your question.